# code for mpstat command in AIX

Tags: aix

I need the code for mpstat command in AIX . I searched the internet but icouldn't get it. Any idea about the structure it uses will also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The excellent nmon tool has been released to open source, so you could look at the source code of that to see where it gets the data you want from.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/WikiPtype/nmon

http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php

Answer (score 0):

Do `iostat` or `vmstat` not serve your needs?   I'm not aware of `mpstat` for AIX.

**EDIT:**
I wasn't aware of mpstat under my older AIX5.2 development machine.   Its available on AIX5.3 and later.

Comment: no dude the output of iostat or vmstat is different from mpstat

Comment: What stat are you looking for from mpstat that the others do not provide?

Comment: @user2, this link has more information about logical/physical CPUs and how to monitor peformance.   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix5_cpu/index.html